# Где хранятся meta теги в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо найти все файлы, хранящие мета-теги keywords, title, description, alt, уникальные для каждой страницы (карточки товара, если данный сайт - онлайн-магазин).

Comment: нет никаких файлов. все в базе

Comment: сами мета теги выводятся в файлах в папке шаблона (обычно), а значения этих тегов в базе данных